# Error 'Could not create an native instance of the type...' when deploying MAUI app to physical iPhone device

Tags: ios, devexpress, maui

I am trying to deploy my first MAUI app to a physical iPhone device in Debug mode. I am doing it from Visual Studio on a pc. The pc is paired with a Mac.

I am getting below error. How can I fix this? The app runs fine on iPhone simulator.

Thanks

Regards

```
[0:] An error occurred: 'Could not create an native instance of the type 'DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXTextEdit': the native class hasn't been loaded.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.'. Callstack: '   at Foundation.NSObject.InitializeObject(Boolean alloced)
   at Foundation.NSObject..ctor(NSObjectFlag x)
   at UIKit.UIResponder..ctor(NSObjectFlag t)
   at UIKit.UIView..ctor(NSObjectFlag t)
   at DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXTextEditBase..ctor(NSObjectFlag t)
   at DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXTextEdit..ctor()
   at DevExpress.Maui.Editors.Internal.TextEditHandler.CreateNativeView()
   at DevExpress.Maui.Core.iOS.Internal.DXViewHandler`2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.TextEdit, DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=23.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXTextEdit, DevExpress.iOS.Editors, Version=23.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].CreatePlatformView()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.TextEdit, DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=23.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXTextEdit, DevExpress.iOS.Editors, Version=23.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].OnCreatePlatformView()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.OnCreatePlatformElement()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.CreatePlatformElement()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.TextEdit, DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=23.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXTextEdit, DevExpress.iOS.Editors, Version=23.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[DevExpress.Maui.Editors.TextEdit, DevExpress.Maui.Editors, Version=23.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a],[DevExpress.iOS.Editors.DXTextEdit, DevExpress.iOS.Editors, Version=23.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.BorderHandler.UpdateContent(IBorderHandler handler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.BorderHandler.MapContent(IBorderHandler handler, IBorderView border)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IBorderView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IBorderHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IBorderView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.BorderHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IBorderView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
```

...

```
The app has been terminated.
```

Comment: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1121521/maui-the-could-not-create-an-native-instance-error

Comment: Hi, Yes this code referred to in that support ticket worked; https://gist.github.com/mattjohnsonpint/37d3ac06a563c41618fc933bf7282d66